# Sending form data using JQuery and parsing the returned JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

This may be a relatively simple task, but I don't know why I've been struggling with it for the past 3 days.

I have to create a login form that sends the email and password to a php file. The php file validates the user and returns JSON data. The JSON returned if the login is successful:

```
enter{"error":0,"message":"User successfully logged in!","api_key":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdHJlZXRlYXRfdXNlcmhhbmRsZXIiLCJleHAiOjE0NDA0Mjg5NDEsImlhdCI6MTQzOTUyODk0MX0.OcDRN4tiQrZPJnpA3Iw2tF4kogYxX-DuDhFqd8vqQts"}
```

If login isn't successful:

```
enter{"error":1,"message":"User doesn't exist!"}
```

The form needs to redirect the user to another html page if the login is successful. I have tried almost every jQuery method ($.post, $.ajax) to send the form data and receive the JSON data but have been unsuccessful so far. The code I tried:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="img.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" class="ui-content">Login</div>
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
<form method="post" action="#" id="loginform">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">

  <br>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-clear-btn="true">
  </div>

  <div>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" data-clear-btn="true">
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="Login" id="login">
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#login").click(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    // Checking for blank fields.
    if (email =='' || password =='') {
      alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }
    else {
      $.post("http://streetdict.esy.es/v1/login",{ email: email, password:password},
        function(data) {
          var json_response=data;
          alert(json_response);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This code basically should just show the JSON response as an alert right? Except that it just doesn't show anything. What I need to do is if the login is successful, it should redirect to another page called untitled.html using ajax, asynchronously. Someone please help me!

Comment: Did you check the network tab in the console to see if a request is made and if the response comes back successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to send post request and then check for response

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#login").click(function(){
 var email = $("#email").val();
 var password = $("#password").val();
 // Checking for blank fields.
 if( email =='' || password ==''){
 alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
  }
 else {

  $.ajax({
     url:'http://streetdict.esy.es/v1/login',
     type:'POST',
     data:{ email: email,  password:password},
     success:function(data){
         if(data['error'] == '0'){
             window.location.href = 'untitled.html';
         }
     },
     error:function(e){
         alert("error in request");
     },
  });

}
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#login").click(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    // Checking for blank fields.
    if (email =='' || password =='') {
      alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }
    else {
      $.getJSON("http://streetdict.esy.es/v1/login",{ email: email,        password:password}).done(function(data) {
           $.each(data, function(key, value) {
//you can do your logic here
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string you response to json.